# Background worker for jQuery Mobile App

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I'm using jQuery mobile with html5 for supporting in Android/iOS devices. Is there any control/technology available to work like a background worker ? What all I need is, I want to push some data to the server in background. Please guide me through this.

Thank You,

Nimmy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_web_workers) but they aren't supported yet by every browser (http://caniuse.com/#search=webworkers).

Comment: Accepting this answer since Web worker support has extended in most of the browsers(and versions), hence resolved this issue.